# How to remove the softlink of /var/tmp -> /var/volatile/tmp

Tags: yocto

In yocto, have the default softlink /var/tmp -> /var/volatile/tmp. I want to remove the softlink.

I try to add a new service but the selinux rule under /var/tmp will be corruption.

So do anybody tells that where does the yocto do this softlink /var/tmp -> /var/volatile/tmp? Want to find the origin point and remove it.  Try to find the service under /lib/systemd/system But have not find the creating softlink service, only find the creatng softlink of /var/lib-> /var/volatile/lib, /var/spool-> /var/volatile/spool,...

Comment: Try adding `VOLATILE_LOG_DIR = "no"` in `local.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `VOLATILE_TMP_DIR = "no"` to your distribution config file. You can also make `/var/log` directory persistent by setting `VOLATILE_LOG_DIR = "no"`.

Note, that these variables are expanded during configuration processing, so they will not work from usual recipes, only from `.conf` files.